Определение начала и окончания системного свайпа назад
Можно ли на Android определить, когда пользователь пытается свайпом сделать шаг назад? onBackPressed говорит только уже о законченном действии.
Моя проблема в том, что я использую WebView и там есть определение удержания пальца на элементе, после которого вызывается какое-то действие. Работает хорошо, только вызывается и при системном свайпе.
На ум приходит только 2 решения:

Блокировать экран при системном свайпе
Определять начало и конец этого события, и сообщать об этом в WebView


